# IIS hosted WCF service accessible from one domain but not the other

Tags: apache-2.4, iis-8.5

I am accessing some api url with address : http://x.x.x.x:25055/CaseStatus.svc/json/21480
I can access this URL directly from my browser, but when I access this url through PHP curl from my live site (hosting server A), I am getting connection refused error.

I've been working on this issue for a whole day now: Here are more details...

1. The api service is written in c# wcf hosted in IIS (Windows Server 2012) on self owned server machine.
2. I've uploaded the same php code to another site (hosting server B) and it is working and returns the json data. (http://www.dailywebsolutions.com/services.php).
3. It is working fine with Chrome App Postman.
4. This leads me to assumption that some configuration problem exists at hosting server A, but I can access other third party APIs via curl from server A without any issues.
5. The only difference between hosting server A and hosting server B is that A has SSL certificate installed but I dont think this should be an issue as I am accessing API service using http.

Any idea what should be the possible cause?

-- I dont think there is any issue with my code, rather seems to me a server configuration issue; that is why I posted my question here instead of stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The possible reason for this issue seems that the port (25055) might not be opened on hosting provider's end. It doesn't look like an SSL issue.

Comment: Yes... I contacted the hosting provider and the issue is resolved now...